# AJAX request from Chrome Extension to Wordpress Website

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developed a chrome extension which extract some data from the user visiting page and I want to transmit them to my database by an AJAX call (my website is a basic wordpress website).

The point is that the ajax response is error 400 and I do not understand where is the problem as I tried to modify my ajax request the best I could.

Here is my AJAX request from content.js

```
/* Popup clicked */

$('#myOwnCustomToolBar_TT91 #message_to_click form.groupio_form #subscribe').on('click', function(){

    //chrome.runtime.sendMessage(product_infos);

    jQuery.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url: "https://www.groupio.fr/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "JSON",
        responseType:'application/json',

        data: {
            action : "itempricingfunction",
            ean : "EANTEST0101010"
        },

        crossDomain:true,

        success:function(data){

            alert(data);

        },

        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });



});
```

Here is my function called itempricingfunction inside the functions.php file of my wordpress theme file

```
function itempricingfunction(){


$product_ean = (isset($_POST['ean'])) ? htmlentities($_POST['ean']) : NULL;
echo json_encode(array('product_ean' =>$product_ean));


    exit;
}

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_itempricingfunction", "itempricingfunction");
add_action("wp_ajax_itempricingfunction", "itempricingfunction");
```

And finally, when I go to the product page and click on the chrome extension, the response of the ajax call is Error 400 (see below on the image) :

[AJAX Response from Wordpress][1]

Thank you very much for your help !

**EDIT after trying to move ajax call into background.js :**

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "XXXX Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The best extension for my friends",

  "icons":{
    "128" : "images/icon128.png",
    "48" : "images/icon48.png",
    "16" : "images/icon16.png"
  },


  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js", "js/background.js"]
  },


  "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "https://www.groupio.fr/"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://www.rddddd.fr/produit/*"],
    "css": ["css/extension_style.css"],
    "js": ["js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js", "js/content.js"]
  }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "images/icon16.png",
   "default_title": "Tayfun Extension",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

    "web_accessible_resources": [

      "toolbar.html",
      "css/extension_style.css",
      "images/logo_extension.png",
      "images/rollback_arrow.png"
  ]

}
```

Here is the new content.js file :

```
/* Popup clicked */

$('#myOwnCustomToolBar_TT91 #message_to_click form.groupio_form #subscribe').on('click', function(){

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(product_infos);


});
```

Here is the new background.js file :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){

        jQuery.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url: "https://www.groupio.fr/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        contentType: 'json',
        dataType: "JSON",
        responseType:'json',

        data: {
            action : "itempricingfunction",
            ean : "EANTEST0101010"
        },

        success:function(data){

            alert(data);

        },

        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
        });

});
```

Comment: `responseType` should be simple `'json'` but the problem is probably different: is this code in a content script that's running in a tab on a different URL (not groupio.fr)? If so, Chrome disallows such cross-origin requests, and you should make them in the background script, see [the official example](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches).

Comment: yes, this code is in a content script and yes it is executed in a different URL that groupio.fr. So I will try to execute it via background.js and communicate the result to the content script by running messages. Thank you, I will try it and tell you if it works for me.

Comment: @wOxxOm I modified the content.js file by a simple sendMessage with product_ean : chrome.runtime.sendMessage(product_infos) and made the exact same ajax call but nothing happen....

Comment: Yes you are right, I edited my initial post and I checked on this tool but the response is still error 400. Hope it could give you a clearer vision of my code.

Comment: @wOxxOm ; here is the complete response : responseText: "0"
responseJSON: 0
status: 400
statusText: "error"

Comment: Seems quite fine, just make sure you've reloaded the extension by clicking the cycle icon on chrome://extensions page, also contentType should be `application/json`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yeap, I reloaded the all extension but it gives me still error 400 and the response text is "0" - the same response when i go to groupio.fr/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. Do you think that functions.php file is not the right file to execute the ajax call. Maybe I should try to create a dedicated php file in my wordpress file ?

Comment: Looks like the extension part is correct so if you don't receive any helpful replies on WordPress or PHP here, maybe it'd be better to open a new question without any extension code but rather using `postman` for requests or a similar test tool, even `curl` will do.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks dude, I will create another question asking for how to interact with wordpress from an external app.